# how to install jquery plugin in grails

Tags: jquery, grails, intellij-idea

I want to use jquery in my project. That's why I am trying to install it by the following command from intellij >>>

```
install-plugin jquery
```

And when command run it gives the following message >>>

```
Failed to install plugin [jquery-1.7.1]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Is this message all you get in the console? usually Grails will log the missing dependencies and where did it try to look for them

Comment: @drorb yes this is the only message I got. Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using install-plugin you can add the plugin to the build config. So in your build config there should be a plugins closure just update so it looks similar to the following (don't remove any plugins already there).

```
plugins {
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
}
```